# How to run two grunt watch tasks simultaneously

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Is it possible to run two watch tasks simultaneously?

I understand that I can have any number of tasks I want inside *watch* settings and just launch *grunt watch* and it will watch all of them, like this

```
...
watch: {
    A: {
        files: "js/dev/**/*.coffee",
        tasks: ["coffee", "requirejs"]
    },
    B: {
        files: "js/dev/**/*.coffee",
        tasks: ["coffee"]
    },
    C: {
        files: "js/dev/**/*.html",
        tasks: ["copy"]
    }
}
...
```

...but I don't need this. I just want to have different set of tasks for development and production. As you can guess, the only difference between *A* (production) and *B* (development) is minification and concatenation. I don't need to launch *A* and *B* tasks at the same time.

First I came with this idea

```
grunt.registerTask("prod", ["watch:A", "watch:C"]);
grunt.registerTask("dev", ["watch:B", "watch:C"]);
```

But this didn't work. Just first watch tasks is working (*C* never works). Is that possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I've found using [grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent) works:

```js
concurrent: {
  options: {
    logConcurrentOutput: true
  },
  prod: {
    tasks: ["watch:A", "watch:C"]
  },
  dev: {
    tasks: ["watch:B", "watch:C"]
  }
}
```

Then:

```js
grunt.registerTask("prod", ["concurrent:prod"]);
grunt.registerTask("dev", ["concurrent:dev"]);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I've got a 'Fatal error : Port 35729 is already in use by another process' when running two watch with concurrent. Any clues ?

Comment: The best and only working solution is there : https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-focus

Comment: @jmcollin92 grunt-focus works well for me, but I am not quite sure why it would be the "best and only working solution". grunt-concurrent works as well, and it can execute any task concurrently. grunt-focus is limited to watch targets.

Comment: @hashchange I agree with you. grunt-focus is only valuable for watch targets. grunt-concurrent works well for all aother purposes.

Comment: @jmcollin92 I got the same 'Fatal error : Port 35729 is already in use by another process' when I first ran this.

I had multiple configurations for my watch config. I just had to set a different livereload port for each one. [Here's a fiddlr](http://jsfiddle.net/dk44x00t/)

Comment: I think that grunt concurrent won't work for you if you are using watch liveReload feature as than every watch task is running in a separate watch process. While focus does work.

Comment: Thank you! You made my day.

Comment: You need to change the port number on livereload config per watch service

Comment: Huge THANKS for this suggestion!

Answer (score 18):

**EDIT:** concurrent now has a `logConcurrentOutput` option! More info here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent#logconcurrentoutput.

Watch is a weirdly concurrent but blocking task, so you have to be creative to get multitask-like functionality working.

Concurrent loses all output from the watch tasks, which isn't ideal.

Try dynamically writing the config object in a custom task:

```
grunt.registerTask('watch:test', function() {
  // Configuration for watch:test tasks.
  var config = {
    options: {
      interrupt: true
    },
    unit: {
      files: [
        'test/unit/**/*.spec.coffee'
      ],
      tasks: ['karma:unit']
    },
    integration: {
      files: [
        'test/integration/**/*.rb',
        '.tmp/scripts/**/*.js'
      ],
      tasks: ['exec:rspec']
    }
  };

  grunt.config('watch', config);
  grunt.task.run('watch');
});
```

Comment: "Concurrent loses all output from the watch tasks": There is a `logConcurrentOutput` option for Concurrent, which prevents just that.

Answer (score 12):

The best and only working solution is there : https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-focus
Add this plugin and then :

```
focus: {
            sources: {
                include: ['js', 'html', 'css', 'grunt']
            },
            testu: {
                include: ['js', 'html', 'css', 'testu', 'grunt']
            },
            testi: {
                include: ['js', 'html', 'css', 'testu', 'testi', 'grunt']
            }
        },
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: paths.js,
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            html: {
                files: paths.html,
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            css: {
                files: paths.css,
                tasks: ['csslint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            testu: {
                files: ['test/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.css'],
                tasks: ['mochaTest'],
                options: {}
            },
            testi: {
                files: ['test/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.css'],
                tasks: ['exec:cleanTestDB', 'protractor_webdriver', 'protractor'],
                options: {}
            },
            grunt: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'server/config/env/*.js'],
                options: {
                    reload: true
                }
            }
        }
```

Then you use focus:sources or focus:testu as your convenience.

JM.

Comment: grunt-concurrent doesn't work with multiple watches that have livereloads for the same port.  This did the trick, thanks!

Comment: `grunt-focus` is great because you can define to watch all but one (or some) tasks, like this: `focus: { dev: { exclude: ['test'] } }` which was great in my case.

Comment: Awesome. Save my life!

Answer (score 7):

grunt-concurrent or grunt-focus are both good solutions, but both of them break `livereload` functionality.

My solution to this is to compose the watch configuration dynamically, with the assumption that you won't be running both configuration at the same time.

You can do something like this

```js
grunt.config.merge({
  watch: {
    options: {
      livereload: true
    },
    C: {
      files: "js/dev/**/*.html",
      tasks: ["copy"]
    }
  }
});

grunt.registerTask('watch-forProd', function () {
  grunt.config.merge({
    watch: {
      A: {
        files: "js/dev/**/*.coffee",
        tasks: ["coffee", "requirejs"]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.task.run('watch');
});

grunt.registerTask('watch-forDev', function () {
  grunt.config.merge({
    watch: {
      B: {
        files: "js/dev/**/*.coffee",
        tasks: ["coffee"]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.task.run('watch');
});

grunt.registerTask("prod", ["watch-forProd"]);
grunt.registerTask("dev", ["watch-forDev"]);
```

Comment: actually grunt-foces doesn't break livereload. you have to include `livereload` option in to every watch target.

Answer (score 4):

**SEPTEMBER 2018**

You don't need to use grunt-concurrent anymore grunt now has this built in, here is a sample from one of my current projects...

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        sass: {
            theme: {
                files: {
                    '../../web/sites/all/themes/ifafri/css/generated/theme_ifafri_master.css' : '../../web/sites/all/themes/ifafri/css/master.scss'
                }
            },
            bootstrap: {
                files: {
                    '../../web/sites/all/themes/ifafri/css/generated/theme_ifafri_bootstrap.css' : '../../web/sites/all/themes/ifafri/css/bootstrap/master.scss' 
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            theme: {
                files: '../../web/sites/all/themes/ifafri/css/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass:theme'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                    livereload: true,
                    nospawn: false
                }
            },
            bootstrap: {
                files: '../../web/sites/all/themes/ifafri/css/bootstrap/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass:bootstrap'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                    livereload: true,
                    nospawn: false
                }
            }
    }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-livereload');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

Comment: **SEPTEMBER 2018** I don't need grunt anymore

Comment: Spawn and nospawn are the same option (nospawn was kept for backwards compatibility). Using nospawn: false at the end will result in spawning processes, which is the default behavior, therefore both ooptions are redundant in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Without worrying grunt.registerTask() in Gruntfile.js, I sometimes run grunt as background processes by typing the following in the command line:

```
$ grunt watch:A &
$ grunt watch:C &
```

You can make the commands as a batch script for more convenience. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this not answer directly to the question, but my solution is now to use Gulp instead of Grunt.
With Gulp you code and not only configure. So you are more free to do what you want.

JM.

Comment: If you like writing all this "Server" utility stuff then gulp is OK. We did an experiment, 1 week to convert our Grunt functionality with Gulp, and we couldn't accomplish the task. I am still on the Grunt side of the fence.

Comment: It tooks me less than one day to do the gulp migration. Very easy to understand, fully featured with tons of plugins and I don't to go back.

Comment: Stoked your experiment went better than ours. I did not personally attempt to do it, maybe it would go easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent works fine for me

```
concurrent: {
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            },
            set1: ['watch:html', 'watch:styles'],
        },

grunt.registerTask('default', 'watch');
grunt.registerTask('htmlcss', ['concurrent:set1']);
```

Comment: Could you please explain more, why it works to help other people to understand, how you composed the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the port address and the livereload port.
For eg. if the port is 9000 change it to 8000 and live reload from 35729 to 36729