# grunt-watch is skipping some of my tasks, why?

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, watch

I've set up a grunt file to automate some of my tasks. I've also split up my watch task into smaller subtasks, to [prevent it becoming one monolithic watch task](http://blog.ponyfoo.com/2013/11/13/grunt-tips-and-tricks).

The individual tasks each used to run perfectly fine, but now it seems that watch is missing some filechanges as they occur. For example, it'll detect a change in my scss and compile that. But it'll miss the subsequent change in the compiled css, and skip the autoprefix and ftp-deploy.

How can I correct this? Do I need to use a debouncedelay, is my watch spawn setting wrong, or is there something else going wrong?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Load all grunt tasks matching the `grunt-*` pattern
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // All configuration goes here 
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // Template strings for directories
    dirs: {
      // Dev
      dev_js: 'js',
      dev_css: 'css',
      dev_scss: 'scss',
      dev_js_authored: '<%= dirs.dev_js %>/authored',
      dev_js_libs: '<%= dirs.dev_js %>/libs',
      dev_js_build: '<%= dirs.dev_js %>/build',
      dev_css_build: '<%= dirs.dev_css %>/build',
      // Production
      prod_server_root: '/wp-content/themes',
      prod_current_theme: '<%= dirs.prod_server_root %>/themename',
      prod_css: '<%= dirs.prod_current_theme %>/css'
    },

    // Template strings for ftp
    ftp_cred: {
      prod_host: 'ip-here',
      prod_auth: 'auth-here'
    },

    // Concatenate
    concat: {   
      js: {
        src: [
          '<%= dirs.dev_js_libs %>/*.js',
          '<%= dirs.dev_js_authored %>/*.js'
        ],
        dest: '<%= dirs.dev_js_build %>/production.js'
      }
    },

    // Minify
    uglify: {
      js: {
        src: '<%= dirs.dev_js_build %>/production.js',
        dest: '<%= dirs.dev_js_build %>/production.min.js'
      }
    },

    // Sass
    sass: {
      compile: {
        options: {
          style: 'compressed'
        },
        files: {
          'css/build/unprefixed.min.css': 'scss/global.scss'
        }
      }
    },

    // Autoprefixer
    autoprefixer: {
      prefix: {
        single_file: {
         src: '<%= dirs.dev_css_build %>/unprefixed.min.css',
         dest: '<%= dirs.dev_css_build %>/production.min.css'
        }
      }
    },

    // FTP
    'ftp-deploy': {
      css: {
        build: {
          auth: {
            host: '<%= ftp_cred.prod_host %>',
            port: 21,
            authKey: '<%= ftp_cred.prod_auth %>'
          },
          src: '<%= dirs.dev_css %>',
          dest: '<%= dirs.prod_css %>',
          exclusions: ['<%= dirs.dev_css_build %>/unprefixed.min.css']
        }        
      }
    },

    // Watch
    watch: {
      scripts_concat: {
        files: ['<%= dirs.dev_js_authored %>/*.js','<%= dirs.dev_js_libs %>/*.js'],
        tasks: ['concat:js']
      },
      scripts_min: {
        files: ['<%= dirs.dev_js_build %>/production.js'],
        tasks: ['uglify:js']
      },
      scss_compile: {
        files: ['<%= dirs.dev_scss %>/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass:compile']
      },
      css_prefix: {
        files: ['<%= dirs.dev_css_build %>/unprefixed.min.css'],
        tasks: ['autoprefixer:prefix']
      },
      ftp_css: {
        files: ['<%= dirs.dev_css_build %>/production.min.css'],
        tasks: ['ftp-deploy:css']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: { livereload: true },
        files: ['<%= dirs.dev_css_build %>/production.min.css','<%= dirs.dev_js_build %>/production.min.js']
      }
    }

  });

  // Load required plugins
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Define what to do at which command
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the mistake (which was a mixup in the folders that I was watching and outputting files to). In the end I changed the watch section to a smaller collection of meaningful task chains, like so:

```
watch: {
  js_prod: {
    files: ['<%= dirs.dev_js_authored %>/*.js','<%= dirs.dev_js_libs %>/*.js'],
    tasks: ['concat:js','uglify:js','ftp-deploy:js_prod','clean:temp_js']
  },
  js_standalone: {
    files: ['<%= dirs.dev_js_standalone %>/*.js'],
    tasks: ['ftp-deploy:js_standalone']
  },
  css_prod: {
    files: ['<%= dirs.dev_scss %>/**/*.scss'],
    tasks: ['sass:compile','autoprefixer:prefix','ftp-deploy:css_prod']
  },
  css_ie: {
    files: ['<%= dirs.dev_css_ie %>/*.css','!<%= dirs.dev_css_ie %>/*.min.css'],
    tasks: ['cssmin:ie','ftp-deploy:css_ie','clean:temp_css_ie']
  },
  livereload: {
    options: { livereload: true },
    files: [
      '<%= dirs.dev_css %>/**/*.css',
      '<%= dirs.dev_js_build %>/production.min.js',
      '<%= dirs.dev_js_standalone %>/*.js']
  }
}
```

This works fine, and I have no more problems with watch tasks not picking up changes, since I won't be working simultaneously in any of the areas they're watching.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `grunt watch:scss_compile`, the `ftp_css` task won't be running and therefore the changes to the *production.min.css*  won't trigger the ftp deployment...

So what you probably want is to run two `watch` tasks simultaneously, with the help of [grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent)

```
concurrent: {
    options: {
        logConcurrentOutput: true
    },
    css: {
        tasks: ["watch:scss_compile", "watch:ftp_css"]
    }
}
```

Then:

```
grunt.registerTask(["concurrent:css"]); // add this task to your default task
```

Have a look at the reference for more details: [How to run two grunt watch tasks simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585385/how-to-run-two-grunt-watch-tasks-simultaneously)

I would, however, separate the `watch` task into two blocks: `js` and `css`, as I assume all `css`-related tasks would have to run upon changes anyway. I would do something like:

```
  css: {
    files: ['<%= dirs.dev_scss %>/**/*.scss'],
    tasks: ['sass:compile', 'autoprefixer:prefix', 'ftp-deploy:css', 'watch:livereload']
  },
  livereload: {
    options: { livereload: true },
    files: [
        '<%= dirs.dev_css_build %>/production.min.css',
        '<%= dirs.dev_js_build %>/production.min.js'
    ]
  }
```